# Sort the list by the field of another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There are two tables:

**Table1**
Id
Name

**Table2**
Id
Table1ID(foreign key Table1 ID)
Date

With EntityFramework I use:

```
var list = db.Table1.Where(some selection).ToList();
```

How can I sort "list" by "Date" field in Table2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using OrderBy on Table2.Date

```
    var list = db.Table1.Where(some selection)
                         .Where(x => x.Table2.Count() > 0)                        
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Table2.FirstOrDefault().Date)ToList();
```